# Swip ViewPager2 is slow

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 7 fragments, I swip between them but it's slow, I did a test adding a fragment that just contains a textView, the swip to this fragment is fast, the difference between my fragments and this one is the amount of components inside.

class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

```
val fragments:ArrayList<Fragment> = arrayListOf(
        Fragment_Onboarding_page1(),
        Fragment_Onboarding_page2(),
        Fragment_Onboarding_page3(),
        Fragment_Onboarding_page4(),
        Fragment_Onboarding_page5(),
        Fragment_Onboarding_page6(),
        Fragment_page6_be_yourself()
)

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fragments.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragments[position]
}
```

}

class EcranAuthentification : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_view_pager)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    initViewPager2WithFragments()
}

private fun initViewPager2WithFragments()
{
    var viewPager2: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
    var adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager,lifecycle)
    viewPager2.adapter = adapter
}
```

}

class Fragment_Onboarding_page2 : Fragment() {

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__onboarding_page2, container, false)

    val viewpager=activity?.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewpager)

    rootView.skip2.setOnClickListener {
        viewpager?.currentItem=6
    }

    rootView.boutonRetour.setOnClickListener {
        viewpager?.currentItem=0
    }
    return rootView
}
```

}

Please can you help me